# Creating an Age Verification Home Page

Tags: php

I want to make a simplish PHP script, which is my home page. I want the user to enter their DOB or choose it from drop down calendars and then, based on what they entered I can check if they are 21 or not. If they are not, I will send them to one page, if they are, I will send them to another page. Here is what I have so far.

```
    <div id="age">
You must be 18 or older to view this site.<br>
  You must be 18 or older to view this site.<br>
    <form action="#" method="post">
    Please input your date of birth:
    <input type="text" name="month">
<input type="text" name="day">
<input type="text" name="year">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verify Age">
    </form>
</div>
        <p></p>

        <?php include "footer.php" ?>
<?php
$month = $_REQUEST['bmonth'];
$day = $_REQUEST['day'];
$year = $_REQUEST['year'];
$this_day = date(d);
$this_month = date(m);
$this_year = date(Y);
$day_val = $this_day - $day;
$month_val = $this_month - $month;
$year_val = $this_year - $year;
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    $today = date_create('today');
    $birth = date_create("{$_POST['year']}-{$_POST['month']}-{$_POST['day']}");
    $age = date_diff($today, $birth)->y;

    if ($age >= 18) {
        header('Location: home.php');
    } else { 
        header('Location: contact.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: _Will this work_ eum try it ?

Comment: yea guess I could, only thing im worried about is the "if($year_val >= 19&&$month_val >= 0&&$day_val >= 0)" not sure if that =21 or not,

Comment: It will work for making your visitors swear at you. If you wonder if it will work preventing juveniles from accessing your site... no.

Comment: why wont it work? mean I know they can lie, but otherwise will it?

Comment: They _can_ lie is the wrong assumption. They _will_ lie. I am not only 18 years old, but old enough to have a child that is 18 years old, but I lie every time some website asks for my date of birth. First, because it's a sensible piece of information that you don't just give to every random person (just like your social security number), and second because I feel offended having to pass "the idiot test". I thus lie about my age if it's a site that I _absolutely_ have to visit, otherwise my reaction is "well, fark you...". In other words, that's one visitor less for your site.

Comment: If you have "strictly adult" content (like pornography or gambling for money) which makes it illegal for you to allow under-age people, you need a better, more reliable verification and must require a login via a secured connection. There exist commercial providers and several countries have governmental age verification programs. Otherwise, just skip the whole idea. Display a warning or a disclaimer, and be done. You cannot prevent people from viewing your _public_ site anyway. So there is no reason to annoy them.

Comment: @Damon: I totally agree with you, but maybe some countries request that kind of "validation". My country has accepted [EU cookie law](http://www.theeucookielaw.com/) which is bacislly the stupidest way to protect the user; all I need to do, to obey the law, is tell user, that this website is using cookies and what cookies are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    $today = date_create('today');
    $birth = date_create("{$_POST['year']}-{$_POST['month']}-{$_POST['day']}");
    $age = date_diff($today, $birth)->y;

    if ($age >= 18) {
        header('Location: example1.php');
    } else { 
        header('Location: example.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: look ok now? I added made it day month year

Comment: for some reason its giving me all these errors "Notice: Undefined index: month
Notice: Undefined index: day 
Notice: Undefined index: year 
Notice: Use of undefined constant d - assumed 'd' 
Notice: Use of undefined constant m - assumed 'm' 
Notice: Use of undefined constant Y - assumed 'Y' 
"

Comment: @Terry: yes, but delete your old php code, like [this](http://pastebin.com/KkPM0jxz). And put PHP code before any output, like [this](http://pastebin.com/wFHZ4bbQ).

Comment: btw, will it work for dates close to the current date? like if I just turned 21 today for example

Comment: Thanks! Accepted your answer also

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$minAge = 18; // You might read this from a file/database.

$minAge *= 3600*24*365.25;  // $minAge in seconds



$html = <<< OET

  You must be 18 or older to view this site.

  <br />

  <form action="#" method="post">

    Please input your date of birth:

    <input type="text" name="dob" value="" />

    <br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verify Age" />

  </form>

OET;



if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $birth_date = strtotime($_POST['dob']);

    $now = strtotime("now");

    $age = $now - $birth_date; // age is in seconds

    if($age > $minAge)

        echo "Over minimum age."; // You could use header here.

    else

        echo "Under minimum age."; // You could use header here.

} else

{

    echo $html;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here Friend: https://gist.github.com/juniorb2ss/a21d5949a91503b9a417

any questions just ask ;)

```
if(!empty($_POST))
{
 $d = $_POST['d'];
 $m = $_POST['m'];
 $y = $_POST['y'];
 $inicio = "$d/$m/$y";
 $fim = Date('d/m/Y', time());

 $b = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $inicio);     
 $e = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fim);     
 $intervalo = $b->diff($e);
 $f = (array)$intervalo;

 if ($f['y'] >= 18) 
 {
     print $intervalo->format('You have %Y years');
     //header('Location: example1.php');
 } 
 else 
 { 
     print $intervalo->format('You have %Y years');
     //header('Location: example.php');
 }
}
```

in form:

```
You must be 18 or older to view this site.<br>
<form action="#" method="post">
Please input your date of birth:
<input type="text" size="2" name="d" value=""> 
/ <input size="2" type="text" name="m" value=""> 
/ <input size="2" type="text" name="y" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verify Age">
</form>
```

Comment: Why would you mix `date()` function with `DateTime class`?

Comment: sorry, not understand

Comment: This `$fim = Date('d/m/Y', time());` and then `$e = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fim);`. You are mixing `date()` and `DateTime`. Why? [You can achive that with `now` keyword](https://eval.in/66990).

Comment: really? was careless even, datetime also does return the current date, just change the code :) `datetime('now');` tanks... https://gist.github.com/juniorb2ss/a21d5949a91503b9a417

Comment: did you update your code? When I used it, all it does it echo how old you are